# Calling a view in macOS from outside a view controller

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

My app uses in app purchases, and if the user is found to not have the premium version, then the class handling the function they tried to use will call on a method from `MKStoryKit`, a class that makes dealing with StoryKit easier. `MKStoryKit` is not a view or a view controller, it's simply for utility. The view I want to call is a custom view which provides them with the features of the premium version and gives the user a few options, while looking a little bit prettier than just a system alert. On my iOS app, after declaring the view from the storyboard (this view has no segues going to it) using:

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
NSString *viewID = @"TermsOfUseQuery";
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *Terms = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewID];
```

I call the following line which simply presents the previously declared UIViewController "Terms" on top of whatever is currently happening:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:Terms animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I was wondering if there was a similar method for macOS, i've been unable to find it. I am aware that, generally, anything "UI" on iOS becomes "NS" and I've already accounted for that, like declaring NSViewController.

As an alternative, I've managed to call the view from inside the main view controller using:

```
    let board:NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewtest:NSViewController = board.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "termsOfUseVC") as! NSViewController
    self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(viewtest)
```

This has the effect that I am looking for, however it has to be achieved from `MKStoryKit` (which is an Objective-C class). I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this, either to just display the view as a modal window at any time (preferred, effectively what that single line does) or to call it as a modal window on top of the current "top" view? Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it, posting this for future reference in case anyone else needs this in the future, or if anyone else tries using Google for this:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowController.contentViewController presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:Terms];
```

This will present a view from the storyboard from the most recent Window of your application, though that "from" part is not too relevant as this will show the View as its own window. If you chose to use:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowController.contentViewController presentViewControllerAsSheet:Terms];
```

Then this would present it as a slidedown from the last window, this is where the window's identity, if you have multiple, matters. The "Terms" present in both lines is a NSViewController that I've shown how to declare in my original answer (Except this is NS instead of UI, macOS vs iOS difference). The actual declaration is below for the sake of clarity:

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
NSViewController *Terms = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"termsOfUseVC"];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For the first option no other windows can be opened
for the second option its impossible to close the window.